# Declare Two Dimensional Vector on Heap

Tags: c++

Declare a two dimensional vector on heap

First approach:

```
vector< vector<CString> *> * lstTableContent = new vector< vector<CString> *>();
int nNumColumns = 10;
int nNumRows = 10;
for (int i = 1; i <= nNumRows ; i++)
{
    vector<CString> *lstTableRow = new vector<CString>();
    for (int j = 1; j <= nNumColumns ; j++)
    {
        lstTableRow->push_back("ITEM");
    }
    lstTableContent->push_back(lstTableRow);
}
return lstTableContent;
```

Second approach:

```
vector< vector<CString> > * lstTableContent = new vector< vector<CString> >();
int nNumColumns = 10;
int nNumRows = 10;
for (int i = 1; i <= nNumRows ; i++)
{
    vector<CString> lstTableRow;
    for (int j = 1; j <= nNumColumns ; j++)
    {
        lstTableRow.push_back("ITEM");
    }
    lstTableContent->push_back(lstTableRow);
}
return lstTableContent;
```

Which approach is the proper one?
How to delete the two dimensional vector?

Comment: You don't need to create `vector` with `new`. Because it manages memory and all elements is in heap.

Comment: The proper one is the one that suits your needs.

Comment: There's no good reason to use `new` for either the outer or the inner vectors.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I want to return the **lstTableContent**. Will using a point which points to the vector be more efficient when passing the vector.

Comment: @dongx: In modern C++, returning a vector will move it, and will be (more or less) as efficient as returning a pointer. Even if you're stuck with an old compiler that doesn't support move semantics, the copy should be elided (making it even more efficient), unless your function has multiple returns, which return different values. Messing around with `new` will  open the door to memory leaks, for little or no benefit

Comment: @dongx you should read about references, it is similar to pointers, but safer. Also in some cases usage differs from pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Better Approach**

```
vector< vector<CString>> lstTableContent;
int nNumColumns = 10;
int nNumRows = 10;
for (int i = 1; i <= nNumRows ; i++)
{
    vector<CString> lstTableRow;
    for (int j = 1; j <= nNumColumns ; j++)
    {
        lstTableRow.push_back("ITEM");
    }
    lstTableContent.push_back(lstTableRow);
}
```

When lstTableContent goes out of scope, everything is descructed properly.

Otherwise, you would have to loop through the vector and delete the individual vectors prior to deleting the vector of vectors (your option 1), or loop through the vector of vectors prior to it going out of scope and deleting the vectors (your option 2).

Comment: If I want to return the lstTableContent. Will using a point which points to the vector of vectors be more efficient when passing the vector around?

Comment: @dongx You can just return the vector itself. The copy will be ellided it will be much more efficient than returning the pointer.

Comment: That will depend on how big the vector is.  In general, yes, returning a pointer to the vector will be more efficient because you're not having to use the copy-constructor (creating several copies of the vector) as you pass it around.  If you have a reason to think efficiency needs to be improved in this regard, look into smart pointer classes (e.g. `unique_ptr`, 'shared_ptr`, etc.) instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Even it is not wrong here: 'for (int i = 1; i <= nNumRows ; i++)' is alarming

Comment: @DieterLücking:  It shouldn't be alarming.  It is the same as `for (int i = 0; i < NumRows; ++i)`.

Answer (score 1):

The first approach should be better when it comes to deleting because each element is just referenced hence destroying the reference will destroy the object.

Answer (score 1):

```
// unsigned size type
const unsigned nNumRows = 10;
// unsigned size type
const unsigned nNumColumns = 10;

vector< vector<CString> > v(nNumRows);
// C/C++ starts counting at zero and ++i for good habit:
for (unsigned i = 0; i < nNumRows ; ++i)
{
    vector<CString>& col = v[i];
    col.reserve(nNumColumns); 
    // Again: C/C++ starts counting at zero and ++j for good habit:
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < nNumColumns ; ++j)
    {
        col.push_back("ITEM");
    }
}
```

Comment: Since he was never referencing items in the vectors using his counters, the 0-based vs 1-based discussion is irrelevant.  He was simply using it to loop over a given number of times.  `for (int i = 0; i < NumRows; ++i)` is equivalent to `for (int i = 1; i <= NumRows; ++i)` in this case.

Comment: @ZacHowland I think the OP is missing it (even the loops are giving same results, in this case)